# Counting number of motor rotations?

Tags: arduino, sensor, motor

I am trying to count the number of times a motor rotates for a fatigue test machine I am building. What type of sensor/electrical component is needed to count the rotations? I plan on having it connected to an Arduino mega and the outputting the number on a basic LCD screen.

Comment: Mechanical counters have built-in non-volatile storage.

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply after counting rotations then one simple solution is a [slotted OPTO](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/displays-optoelectronics/optocouplers-photodetectors-photointerrupters/slotted-optical-switches/) and a disk with a single slot. This will produce a pulse every rotation & this can be used to increment a register/variable.

I have done something similar using a scraped CD & a black permanent pen more as absolute reference when comparing other parameters.

[image]
suitable image found via google.

Answer (score 1):

Paint a black stripe on the shaft with a sharpie, then illuminate the shaft so that the light from it reflects onto a phototransistor.